# How can i implement generics here?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, stack, queue

This code attempts to emulate a queue using two stacks but should be able to accept any data type. However, what I have added seems to not do the trick and on the first enqueue, eclipse throws this: The method enqueue(T) in the type Queue2Stacks is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Does anyone know what the proper syntax would be? Thank you!

This is the code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Queue2Stacks<T> {

Stack<T> stack1 = new Stack<T>(); 
Stack<T> stack2 = new Stack<T>(); 

/*
 *  1. Method: ENQUEUE
 *  
 *  This simulates the "Enqueue" method in Queues
 *  
 *  But in this case, we use a stack. For enqueue, we add to stack 1
 */

public void enqueue(T data) {
    stack1.push(data);  
    System.out.println("enqueue done");                                                 // DELETE!!
}

/*
 *  2. Method: DEQUEUE
 *  
 *  This simulates the "Dequeue" method in Queues
 *  
 *  We use two stacks to achieve this. We first transfer nodes from stack 1 to stack 2 using pop and push
 *  Then we pop off the items in stack 2 which will now be in "Queue" order
 */

public void dequeue() {
    int stackOgSize = stack1.size();
    
    if (stack2.isEmpty()) {
        // pop all of the items in stack 1 and add them to stack 2 with push, then pop off from stack 2
        for(int i=0; i< stackOgSize; i++) {
            T transferrable = stack1.pop();
            stack2.push(transferrable);
        }
    }
    // pop off from stack 2
    System.out.println(stack2.peek());                                                          // DELETE!!
    stack2.pop();
}

// Run the methods
public static void main(String[] args) {
    enqueue("a");
    enqueue("b");
    enqueue("c");
    
    dequeue();  // should return "a"
    
    enqueue("f");
    enqueue("j");
    enqueue("k");
    
    dequeue();  // should return "b", then "c"
    dequeue();
    
    dequeue();   // then "f" and "j"
    dequeue();

}

}
```

Comment: You have to first create an instance of the class, and then call the methods. Notice that you are calling instance methods and without an instance the type inferrence algorithm can't infer t he types too. Here's a corrected one. `Queue2Stacks<String> q2s = new Queue2Stacks<>();  q2s.enqueue("a"); // ...`

Comment: Thank you!! This makes a lot of sense, and it worked. Appreciate it!